# Unable to unload DLL in .NET Core 3

Tags: dll, .net-core, .net-assembly

I am trying to unload an external assemble but it still sitting in the memory and I can not delete the dll file. Here is my code - What am I doing wrong ?

The uploaded dll is very simple - just 1 class and one method. no dependencies.

I had a look at many samples and see no issue in the code but it still does not work.

Thank you !

```
class SimpleUnloadableAssemblyLoadContext : AssemblyLoadContext
{
    public SimpleUnloadableAssemblyLoadContext( ) : base(isCollectible: true)
    {
    }
    protected override Assembly Load(AssemblyName name)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public class PluginLoader2
{

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    public string getExternalText()
    {
        string res = "";
        var sourcesPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Plugins");

        string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(sourcesPath);
        foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
        {
            SimpleUnloadableAssemblyLoadContext context = new SimpleUnloadableAssemblyLoadContext();
            WeakReference w_r = new WeakReference(context, trackResurrection: true);

            var myAssembly = context.LoadFromAssemblyPath(fileName);

            context.Unload();
            for (var i = 0; i < 10 && w_r.IsAlive; i++)
            {
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            }
            res += "<br /><br />" + fileName + " live status is " + w_r.IsAlive.ToString();
        }

        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please stop using the [tag:assembly] tag for your [tag:.net-assembly] questions.  And also [tag:core] is not about .net-core.  Read the tag popups, don't just type random text into the tag field.

Comment: So to clarify, your problem is that you want to Delete the assembly once it was loaded?

Comment: yes - unload it. this code does not unload it for some reason.